# Prevent an element from rerendering on setState in React Native

Tags: react-native, setstate, use-state

I am using `setState` in order to dynamically update an image's source when a button is pushed in React Native. However, I am also using the TypeWriter library which types out text with a special 'typewriter' animated effect.

When my setState is called to change the element and the page is rerendered, TypeWriter types the text out again. I don't want this. Is there a way to exclude my TypeWriter text from being rerendered?

Code snippet:

```
export const AccountScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

this.state = {
  img1Src: require('../assets/img/token.png')
}

const [state, setState] = useState(this.state);

changeImgSrc = () =>{
  setState({
    img1Src: require('../assets/img/X2.png')
  })
}

return (
        <TypeWriter> //I don't want this to re-render on setState
          <Text>My Account</Text>
        </TypeWriter>

        <Animatable.Image source={state.img1Src}/>

        <Button onPress={this.changeImgSrc}>
            Click me!
        </Button>

etc...//
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export const NewComponent = ({ navigation }) => {

const [state, setState] = useState({
  img1Src: require('../assets/img/token.png')
});

changeImgSrc = () =>{
  setState({
    img1Src: require('../assets/img/X2.png')
  })
}

return (
    <Animatable.Image source={state.img1Src}/>

    <Button onPress={this.changeImgSrc}>
        Click me!
    </Button>
    etc...//
```

You can make a new component is called NewComponent. Then,

```
export const AccountScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

return (
    <TypeWriter> //I don't want this to re-render on setState
      <Text>My Account</Text>
    </TypeWriter>
    <NewComponent />
 etc...//
```

Also, you cannot use this in the functional component. In addition, if you want to call a function in functional component, you must use it with useCallback.